# Is is possible to change one regional setting for Wine applications - use decimal dot instead of comma for numbers?

Tags: wine, playonlinux, locale, microsoft-office, localization

On my Ubuntu MATE<sup>1</sup> 18.04 LTS I use various applications driven by Wine and/or PlayOnLinux.

I see that for example Word 2007 think that I have comma as decimal number separator, this breaks some field functionality.

So I need to change comma (« . ») to dot (« . ») in Wine's regional settings.

---

1. official Ubuntu [flavor](https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible by using methods below:

- for Wine one can launch Wine Registry Editor by

  - for default prefix

    ```
    wine regedit
    ```
  - for custom prefix

    ```
    WINEPREFIX=~/path/to/wine-prefix wine regedit
    ```

  and change the corresponding value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International\sDecimal` from `,` to `.`;
- for PlayOnLinux

  1. select needed application
  2. click Configure
  3. navigate to Wine tab
  4. click Registry Editor button
  5. navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International` and then set `sDecimal` to `.`

Then relaunch needed application and check that regional settings are now applied.